# Non-homogenenous PDE: method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am very new here after a friend recommended this site. I am preparing for my final graduation exam there is one question I can not solve:

I was hoping perhaps someone could help me.

$$a= a(x,y)$$
$$a a_{xy} = a_x a_y = xy$$ 
$$a(x,0) = x$$
(so $a$ differentiated w.r.t. $x$ and $y$).

I need to find the solution of a using the method of characteristics. I only knew how to solve it using direct integration but this was not allowed

Thanks in advance

Greetings from Barcelona

Comment: Please use TEX for typing the equation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Here is a quick [TeX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I can try to format your equation properly, but you should check that I did not change its meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing 5PM indeed, this is indeed the equation!